# How do I export Datagridview details to crystal report

Tags: c#, linq, crystal-reports

I'm using Linq to Sql in my project, and the datagridview populated by a a stored procedure called `Get_All_Incomes`.

I design a Crystal Report to view data from the gridview but there is an exception

> DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>

I populate the gridview with this code

```
dgvIncome.DataSource = CLS_Incomes.Get_All_Incomes().ToList();
```

I filter the gridview using this method

```
string nameFilter = txtCust.Text;
string mediaFilter = comboMedia.SelectedIndex > 0 ? comboMedia.Text : "";
string currencyFilter = comboCurr.SelectedIndex > 0 ? comboCurr.Text :"";
string motalabahFilter = txtMot.Text;
string sanadFilter = txtSanad.Text;
string incomeFilter = txtIncome.Text;
DateTime? fromDate = radioFrom.Checked ? dateTimePicker1.Value.Date : (DateTime?)null;
DateTime? toDate = radioFrom.Checked ? dateTimePicker2.Value.Date : (DateTime?) null;

        using (dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext())
        {
            var result = from p in db.Get_All_Incomes()
                where
                    (nameFilter.Length > 0 && p.CustomersName.Contains(nameFilter) || nameFilter.Length == 0)
                    && (mediaFilter.Length > 0 && p.Name == mediaFilter || mediaFilter.Length == 0)
                    && (currencyFilter.Length > 0 && p.CurrencyName == currencyFilter || currencyFilter.Length == 0)
                    && (motalabahFilter.Length > 0 && p.Motalabah == motalabahFilter || motalabahFilter.Length == 0)
                    && (sanadFilter.Length > 0 && p.Sanad == sanadFilter || sanadFilter.Length == 0)
                    && (incomeFilter.Length > 0 && p.Income.ToString() == incomeFilter || incomeFilter.Length == 0)
                    &&
                    ((fromDate == null || toDate == null) ||
                     (fromDate != null && toDate != null && p.SanadDate >= fromDate && p.SanadDate <= toDate))

                select p;


            dgvIncome.DataSource = result.ToList();
```

Finally called the report using this button

```
btnReport.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
Reports.Rpt rpt = new Reports.Rpt();
rpt.SetDataSource(dgvIncome.DataSource);
FRM_Report frm = new FRM_Report();
btnReport.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your code above seems fine, check your "date...null" codeline. That could be the problem. Did you try tracing the code that gives the exception? Also, how did you design your crystal report? I suspect that the problem lies with the way the dataset in question is populated. Kindly let me know your findings.